# public function vba language

Tags: excel, vba

I have to scroll a column of data, and when i find a different value from the privious cell (n <> n-1), i have to add a row.

I tried to set up to use public function 'cause i need for all worksheets , but does'nt work:

```
Public Sub f()

For i = 1 To FinalRow

  If Cells(row, 4) <> Cells(row - 1, 4) Then
    cell(i, 4).Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAboven.Delete
    Count = Count + 1
  End If

Next i

End Sub
```

What is wrong?
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you explain why or what doesn't work with your function? Where does the FinalRow variable come from (it doesn't seem to hold a value)? And why do you need the count = count +1 ?

Comment: i have to insert this txt in the marco's txt. i have a stack of name of cities, the are sorted, and when the macro scroll the column should add a row when the name of the city is different with the previous

Comment: Can you further clarify what you want to achieve. You're seems to be using a lot of variables that was not actually used. Perhaps illustrate a simple sample data?

Comment: Example:
london
london
london
new york
new york 
seattle
seattle
seattle
setalle

My macro result's should be:

london
london
london

new york
new york 

seattle
seattle
seattle
setalle
i have to insert a new row when a find a different value than the previous

Comment: @user3619429 Where did you get this code? Do you understand what the code you wrote does so far? You write "...but doesn't work", so we would like to know what exactly doesn't work: it doesn't do anything/it gives you a specific error(which error and which line of code)/it only works one time/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub f()

    Dim totalRows As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long

    currentRow = 1 'Start parsing in row 1
    totalRows = 9 'Replace with your total

    Do While currentRow <= totalRows
        'Compare it to the next row
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & currentRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & (currentRow + 1)).Value Then
            'They are the same -> go to the next row
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Else
            'They are different -> insert a row (and add it to the total)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & currentRow).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            currentRow = currentRow + 2 'You want to parse the next row but skip the one you inserted
            totalRows = totalRows + 1
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```